# Semaphore with NSRunLoop not working since upgrade to iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore, nsrunloop

I'm using the official Ricoh Theta iOS SDK ([Link](https://developers.theta360.com/en/docs/sdk/download.html)) in my app to connect to a 360° Ricoh Theta Camera. The SDK uses multiple HTTP requests to trigger the capturing of images and download images from the camera.

Internally the SDK uses semaphores to synchronize the requests, but since upgrading to iOS 10 this seems to not work anymore for some reason. According to the developer forums the issue is known, but Ricoh apparently doesn't really care.

I narrowed it down to a particular part in the SDK where the SDK checks in a loop if an image is available by sending a request every 0.5s through a RunLoop.

This happens in this function:

```
/**
 * Start status monitoring
 * @param command ID of command to be monitored
 * @return Status indicating completion or error
 */
- (NSString*)run:(NSString*)command
{
    // Create and keep HTTP session
    NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    _session= [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

    _commandId = command;

    // Semaphore for synchronization (cannot be entered until signal is called)
    _semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    // Create and start timer
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.5f
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(getState:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
    NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runLoop addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [runLoop run];

    // Wait until signal is called
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(_semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    NSLog(@"HERE");
    return _state;
}
```

The problem is that `NSLog(@"HERE");` is never called even though the Semaphore is triggered in the getState Method (`dispatch_semaphore_signal(_semaphore);`). I know this for sure by stepping through the lines in the debugger.

```
/**  
  * Delegate called during each set period of time  
  * @param timer Timer  
  */
- (void)getState:(NSTimer*)timer {
    // Create JSON data
    NSDictionary *body = @{@"id": _commandId};

    // Set the request-body.
    [_request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:body options:0 error:nil]];

    // Send the url-request.
    NSURLSessionDataTask* task =
    [_session dataTaskWithRequest:_request
               completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                   if (!error) {
                       NSArray* array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
                       _state = [array valueForKey:@"state"];
                       _fileUri = [array valueForKeyPath:@"results.fileUri"];
                       NSLog(@"result: %@", _state);
                   } else {
                       _state = @"error";
                       NSLog(@"GetStorageInfo: received data is invalid.");
                   }
                   if (![_state isEqualToString:@"inProgress"]) {
                       [timer invalidate];
                       dispatch_semaphore_signal(_semaphore);


                       // Stop timer
                       [timer invalidate];
                   }
               }];
    [task resume]; }
```

I've seen there have been some minor changes to the NSRunLoop in iOS 10, is this maybe related to what I'm facing here? An other feeling I got is that maybe iOS is failing to get a new thread that will call `dispatch_semaphore_wait`.

I've been banging my head against the table for the last couple of hours, really hoping that one of you guys can help out here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the semaphore.

The [documentation for `-[NSRunLoop run]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsrunloop/1412430-run?language=objc) says:

> Puts the receiver into a permanent loop, during which time it
>   processes data from all attached input sources.
>   […]
>
> If no input sources or timers are attached to the run loop, this
>   method exits immediately; otherwise, it runs the receiver in the
>   `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` by repeatedly invoking `runMode:beforeDate:`. In
>   other words, this method effectively begins an infinite loop that
>   processes data from the run loop’s input sources and timers.
>
> **Manually removing all known input sources and timers from the run loop
>   is not a guarantee that the run loop will exit. macOS can install and
>   remove additional input sources as needed to process requests targeted
>   at the receiver’s thread. Those sources could therefore prevent the
>   run loop from exiting.**
>
> **If you want the run loop to terminate, you shouldn't use this method.**
>   Instead, use one of the other run methods and also check other
>   arbitrary conditions of your own, in a loop. A simple example would
>   be:
>
> ```
> BOOL shouldKeepRunning = YES; // global
> NSRunLoop *theRL = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
> while (shouldKeepRunning && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);
> ```
>
> where `shouldKeepRunning` is set to `NO` somewhere else in the program.

Pay special attention to the sentences I've bolded. There's no reason to expect that any code in the `-run:` method after the `[runLoop run]` call will ever be executed.

It seems like the original programmers hoped that invalidating the timer would remove the last input that was keeping the run loop running and it would return from its `-run` method. That hope is not justified. The fact that it worked in some cases on some versions of the OS was unlucky happenstance. (Unlucky because if it hadn't worked, they would have realized their mistake and found a different approach.)

If you attempt to use Apple's suggested workaround, be warned that it only works if an input source (not a timer) is what sets `shouldKeepRunning` to false. That's because, as documented, `-runMode:beforeDate:` doesn't necessarily return when a timer fires. So, you'll need to use an input source to trigger the exit.

You can use an `NSPort` to "poke" the run loop. You can use `-performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`, targeting the thread which is running the loop. You can't do cross-thread `NSRunLoop` access, but you can drop down to the `CFRunLoop` API, which is thread-safe, via `-getCFRunLoop`. Then, you can use `CFRunLoopPerformBlock()` and `CFRunLoopWakeUp()` to run a block which sets `shouldKeepRunning` to false. The `-run:` method should `CFRetain()` the `CFRunLoop` and then the code which calls `CFRunLoopWakeUp()` should `CFRelease()` it, just to make sure it lives for as long as needed. Otherwise, there's a potential race condition between the original thread and any final work inside of `CFRunLoopWakeUp()`.

All of that said, you may be able to replace a lot of this by using a GCD dispatch timer source rather than an `NSTimer` and then stop using `NSRunLoop` stuff. That depends on whether `-getState:` really needs to run on the same thread as `-run:`. With the current code, it does run on that same thread. With a dispatch timer source, it would not. It's a bit hard to say with only partial code, but it looks to me like there shouldn't be any problem using the dispatch timer source.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailed answer! I really appreciate it!
I found this gist, which would follow your suggested approach (https://gist.github.com/maicki/7622108), nevertheless I'm wondering now how to include it in the existing SDK. Using a dispatch timer I might forced to use a completion block, but currently the SDK returns the value after waiting in a synchronous way for the semaphore. Is there a way to combine those two approaches?

Comment: You would still use the semaphore. It's just that you'd replace the `NSTimer` with a dispatch timer source and then you wouldn't need to run the run loop.

Comment: Makes sense! You made my day, seriously can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

I made following changes and it just worked for me.

```
- (NSString*)run:(NSString*)command{
NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

_session= [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

_commandId = command;

_semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.5f
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(getState:)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];

NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

[runLoop addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

[runLoop run];

dispatch_semaphore_wait(_semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

return _state;
}


- (void)getState:(NSTimer*)timer{
if ([_state isEqualToString:@"done"])
{
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(_semaphore);
    [timer invalidate];
    return;
}
NSDictionary *body = @{@"id": _commandId};

[_request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:body options:0 error:nil]];

NSURLSessionDataTask* task =
[_session dataTaskWithRequest:_request
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSArray* array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
                    _state = [array valueForKey:@"state"];
                    _fileUri = [array valueForKeyPath:@"results.fileUri"];
                    NSLog(@"result: %@", _state);
                } else {
                    _state = @"error";
                }
                if (![_state isEqualToString:@"inProgress"]) {

                }
            }];
[task resume];}
```

hope this will help someone.